# What does +Mat mean?

Tags: scala, akka-stream

Lookint at the definition of the Flow class on https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/stream/scaladsl/Flow.html, it has the 
following signature:

```
 final class Flow[-In, +Out, +Mat]
```

The question is, why is the type of the third parameter is `+Mat`? I thought, `+Mat` makes only sense on `Sink`, because
`Sink` consumes the stream.
Even the `Source` has the `+Mat`:

```
final class Source[+Out, +Mat]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each stage materializes in some value, this is what gives you the ability to obtain a mechanism to push elements into the stream via a `SourceQueueWithComplete` when you use a `Source.queue`.

Even a Flow could materialize in some value but this isn't common, in this cases you'll see that the materialized value is `NotUsed`.